# How do I add button in each row of column of already bound datagridview in Windows application?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to add a button to each row of a column of an already bounded datagridview, and add an event to it (in VS 2005, Windows application).

I have searched a lot but was unable to find a working solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

before binding to the datasource set :

```
grd.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

create yourself all DataGridView columns and bind them to the datasource:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
dgvc.HeaderText = "column_header";
dgvc.DataPropertyName = "column_name";
```

create a DataGridViewButtonColumn.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn dgvbt = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
```

If you want this column not bound, set header text, the same text on all buttons:

```
dgvbt.HeaderText = "OK?";
dgvbt.Text = "ok";                        // works also when bound
dgvbt.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true; //
```

If you want your column to be also bounded and each button have the text of underlying cell, bind it:

```
dgvbt.DataPropertyName = "column_bt";
```

Add created columns to the DataGridView:

```
grd.Columns.Add(dgvc);
grd.Columns.Add(dgvbt);
```

handle the CellClick event of the DataGridView:

```
grd.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(grd_CellClick);


void grd_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == index_of_button_column)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, e.RowIndex.ToString() + " Clicked!");
        //...
    }
}
```

for more, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx