# Handle clicking by state of button in Datagridview C#

Tags: c#

I'd like to create a button. First click for doing somethings. Then the second click would do somethings different with the first

Example :

- First Click : Thread.Start();
- Second Click : Thread.Stop();

This is just example. Two clicks in one button.

Comment: These have lots of way to implement. You have 3 options: First is adding `Tag` on each button as boolean type, then trigger the changes of its view to get, set these values. Second, Googling Toggle Switch Button library for Winforms. WPF and UWP already built-in this control. Third, using checkbox control to handle it.

Comment: Maybe you can just create a global(outstide function) flag to store the boolean state, and use !flag  in condition, then you can run as you want.

Comment: :V can you give me a explame pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple improvement logical base on [adding button topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410070/how-do-i-add-button-in-each-row-of-column-of-already-bound-datagridview-in-windo)

Create button column and add it into columns, then add 2 rows sample

```
        DataGridViewButtonColumn dvButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dvButton.HeaderText = "MyButton";
        dvButton.Name = "MyButton";

        dataGridView.Columns.Add("MyColumn", "MyText");
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(dvButton);

        dataGridView.Rows.Add("Text 1", "Start");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add("Text 2", "Start");
```

Add event for cell click

```
        dataGridView.CellClick += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView.Columns.IndexOf(dvButton))
            {
                var cell = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
                MessageBox.Show($"Row {e.RowIndex.ToString()} with [{cell.Value}] clicked");

                HandleValue(cell);
            }
        };
```

And the handle function

```
    public void HandleValue(DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        switch (cell.Value.ToString())
        {
            case "Start":
                //Handle started
                cell.Value = "Stop";
                break;
            case "Stop":
                //Handle stopped
                cell.Value = "Start";
                break;
        }
    }
```

The result:

Before clicking

[image]

After clicked

[image]

Comment: anh ơi :V em có fb anh . EM có thể Ib hỏi vài cái đc không . cài này em vẫn có chỗ vướng mắc

Answer (score 0):

For a button that has only two states, use a ToggleButton

```
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(toggleButton.isChecked)
    {
        Thread.Start();
    } else {
        Thread.Stop();
    }
}
```

If you want more states, you could use a counter and a "switch-case" statement. You just need a way to reset your counter.

```
int count=0;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){

switch (count){
    case 0:
       //do things
       count++;
       break;

    case 1:
       //do other things
       count++;
       break;

    case 2:
       //do things different
       count++;
       break;
}
```

Comment: :V but title Is button in datagirdview . I need it because it use for each row

Comment: If you want to know how to add buttons for each row in a DataGridView look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410070/how-do-i-add-button-in-each-row-of-column-of-already-bound-datagridview-in-windo

Comment: i know how to create a button . But i need when you click it . Expamle first click it show message box : Click 1 . IF you click again . It will show Already CLick .